# Casting invalid string date to date in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column with invalid date strings in snowflake and I need to cast them to date. I tried with TRY_CAST, TRY_DATE, IS_DATE but nothings seems to work, i.e.

`select * from (values (1, TRY_CAST('1985-02-30' as date)));`

Invalid expression [TRY_CAST('1985-02-30' AS DATE)] in VALUES clause

Is there an easy way to do a validation on the date itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `VALUES` requires simple expression or constants. The alternative is `SELECT`:

```
select * from (values (1, TRY_CAST('1985-02-30' as date)));
=>
select * from (select 1, TRY_CAST('1985-02-30' as date));
```